# Running a single specflow test starts the entire test suite

Tags: c#, specflow

I am having a specflow test suite in C# that is running through visual studio. The problem is that recently I started having some issues with running the test. Every time I start a test, instead of that specific test to run the entire suite starts.

I cannot post the code because it is confidential, but I was wondering if anyone has faced this issue before or if you have any idea of a setting I can check in order to fix the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's much easier to help you if you can [edit] your post with a [mre]. Start from scratch and see what you need to do to reproduce the problem without involving your company's code.

Comment: I have faced this issue before, but we need more information. Can you describe how you are running a single test? Are you choosing a single test in Test Explorer and running that? Which buttons are you clicking?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it through selecting all tests, not only the ones that were not run.